# SubSonic and SQL Azure

Tags: subsonic, data-access-layer, azure-sql-database, telerik-open-access

I wrote an e-commerce app and used SubSonic 2.2 to generate the Data-Access-Layer.
It works perfectly with Sql Server 2005 and 2008.
However I would like to add support for SQL Azure.

**Does anyone know if the code generated by SubSonic 2.2 with work with SQL Azure?**

Side note:
If there are big issues I may scrap the 2 yrs old Data-Access-Layer and use Telerik ORM.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not that familiar with SQL Azure, but I understand it supports T-SQL.  In that case, it shouldn't be *too* difficult to adapt SubSonic to it.

However, changing the template files will not be enough, you will need to modify the source project and rebuild it.  I say this because the SubSonic dll contains references to the various ADO.Net providers it supports (Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, MySql.Data, System.Data.SQLite, System.Data.SqlServerCe).

Comment: becareful with SubSonic, my understanding is that it uses MSDTC under the covers. MSDTC isn't supported on Windows Azure at this stage.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider / strongly advise using something like EntityFramework which is fully supported. Other fully support ORMs include Lightspeed, nHibernate etc.